# Returning a symbol n amount of times

Tags: scheme

makelist is a procedure that takes an item and an integer n and returns the item n amount of times.

```
(define (makelist (n item)
    (cond
      [(null? item) '()]
      [else (cons item (makelist (- n 1)))])))
```

my procedure returns a syntax error, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use: `(make-list n item)` :)

Your syntax error is due to incorrect `define`.

It should be:

```
(define (makelist n item) ...
```

Note that you have a extra `(` before the `n`.

Comment: @FrankieV. - If you're going to be programming in lisp for any length of time, look into [autopairs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs) or [paredit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) or both. A [highlighter](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightParentheses) wouldn't hurt either. I'm sure comparable utilities exist for whatever editor you're using, even if it isn't Emacs. No Lisper I know keeps track of parens manually.

Comment: Indeed, Vim has a Scheme syntax module and will help track your parentheses ;)